# match portions of an optional section

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex set up to match a US-formatted date and time.  It looks like this:

```
/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})(am|pm|AM|PM|Am|Pm)/
```

However, I need it to also match dates that do not contain the time component.

How do I modify this, so that if it's a date, I get 3 matches, and if it's a date-time, I get six?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the time and make it [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

```
/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})(?: (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})(am|pm|AM|PM|Am|Pm))?/
```

The `?:` suppresses capturing, so that you don't end up with an additional group if the time is present.

Also, if you're not too picky about allowing `aM` and `pM`, you can simplify considerably with a case-insensitive modifier:

```
/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})(?: (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})([ap]m))?/i
```

In fact, using `?` you can even shorten the pattern further, (because `\d?` is shorter than `{1,2}`:

```
/(\d\d?)\/(\d\d?)\/(\d{2,4})(?: (\d\d?):(\d\d?)([ap]m))?/i
```

Note however, that in any case you will still get 6 groups (7 if you count the overall match) - it's just that the last three will be `undefined`:

```
> groups = '11/11/11'.match(/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})(?: (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})([ap]m))?/i)
["11/11/11", "11", "11", "11", undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

The same happens when using `exec` instead. But these are easy to filter out if necessary:

```
> groups.filter(function(capture) {
      return typeof capture !== 'undefined';
  });
["11/11/11", "11", "11", "11"]
```

or in this case (because you can never have empty strings as captures):

```
> groups.filter(function(capture) {
      return capture;
  });
["11/11/11", "11", "11", "11"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `?` around time regex, wrapper with `(?:)` non-capturing group.

```
/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})(?:\s+(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})(am|pm|AM|PM|Am|Pm))?/
```

Note that literal space has been replaced with `\s+`.

`+` - match 1 or more

`*` - match 0 or more

`?` - match 0 or 1

Comment: While there is no better solution, please note that this will not yield an array with only 4 elements.

Comment: 4 elements? sorry, didn't get you. where's that in question?

Comment: The OP wants "only 3 matches", so I think it's worth pointing out that the array you obtain when using the pattern in `match` or `exec` will still have the same amount of elements. It's just that some of them will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})(?: (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})(am|pm|AM|PM|Am|Pm))?/
```

Or even shorten your regex:

```
/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})(?: (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})([ap]m))?/i
```

I wrapped the space and the time into a non-capture group and put a `?` for 0 or 1 times occurrence to make the time optional.

The character class `[ap]` matches either `a` or `p` and since both `am` and `pm` end with `m`, you can simply use `[ap]m` and a case insensitive modifier to make `[ap]m` match both upper and lower case characters.

Comment: While there is no better solution, please note that this will not yield an array with only 4 elements. Also, you dropped capturing the `am/pm` bit.

Comment: Must have happened during the shortening xD Thanks!